# Increase speed of a function call in Matlab

Tags: performance, function, matlab, call

I have code with a call function that gives the Type of each gene in system. I can find it by comparing the order of each gene with its children and parent. The code is working fine with a small amout of cell arrays, but when I increase the amount to thousands it takes hours. The code is:

```
Types=[];
type1=level1_root; % it is fixed value (GO:0008150)
% sample values for p1 and c1 are given below
for k=1:100
    type{k}=type_fc(p1,c1,type1); % a function call - see function below
    type1=type{k}'; %'
    temp1=num2cell(repmat(k+1,length(type1),1));
    type1=[type1 temp1];
    Types=[Types; type1];
 end
 % display the output:
 Types
```

The sub function:

```
function type=type_fc(p1,c1,type1)
type=[];
for j=1:length(type1)
    for i=1:length(p1)
        a=[p1(i),c1(i)];
        if isequal(a(1), type1(j))
            type=[type a(2)];
        end
    end
end
```

For 13 genes I have these sample inputs:

```
p1'= %refer to parent genes  
      'GO:0008150'
      'GO:0016740'
      'GO:0016787'
      'GO:0008150'
      'GO:0016740'
      'GO:0016740'
      'GO:0016787'
      'GO:0016787'
      'GO:0016787'
      'GO:0006810'
      'GO:0006412'
      'GO:0004672'


 c1'=  % refer to children genes    
  'GO:0016740'
  'GO:0016787'
  'GO:0006810'
  'GO:0006412'
  'GO:0004672'
  'GO:0016779'
  'GO:0004386'
  'GO:0003774'
  'GO:0016298'
  'GO:0016192'
  'GO:0005215'
  'GO:0030533'
```

And the result will be: `Types =`

```
  'GO:0016740'    [2]
  'GO:0006412'    [2]
  'GO:0016787'    [3]
  'GO:0004672'    [3]
  'GO:0016779'    [3]
  'GO:0005215'    [3]
  'GO:0006810'    [4]
  'GO:0004386'    [4]
  'GO:0003774'    [4]
  'GO:0016298'    [4]
  'GO:0030533'    [4]
  'GO:0016192'    [5]
```

Do you have any idea how to increase the speed of this code?

Comment: If you have similar questions, you can give [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) a try

Answer (score 7):

At first glance, I can spot a few issues in your code:

1. First and foremost, `Types` and `type` are dynamically growing inside the loop. This can be extremely expensive in MATLAB in terms of execution time. Instead, preallocate memory before the loop (that is, create the array with the predetermined final number of elements), and you may witness a dramatic increase in performance.
2. You're using loops. If there's a vectorized solution (I haven't checked that out yet), it might take significantly less time to compute.
3. You're using `i` and `j` indices as the variable names of loop iterators. These variables already have another purpose: they represent the imaginary unit `sqrt(-1)`. MATLAB still allows using `i` and `j` for variable names, but the variable name resolution that it does in order to figure out the correct context does have a small cost. You should rather pick other names, even `ii` and `jj`.
   *EDIT: the same goes for `type`, it is already a [reserved function name](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/type.html) in MATLAB.*

Try the following optimized version, it should run faster by at least an order of magnitude:

```
Types = cell(numel(c1), 2);      % # Preallocate memory
type1 = level1_root;             % # ... or p1{1}
kk = [1, 2];                     % # Initialize indices
while ~isempty(type1)
    type_fc = cellfun(@(x)c1(strcmp(x, p1)), type1, 'Uniform', false);
    type1 = vertcat(type_fc{:});
    idx = kk(1):kk(1) + numel(type1) - 1;
    Types(idx, 1) = type1;
    Types(idx, 2) = {kk(2)};
    kk = kk + [numel(type1), 1]; % # Advance indices
end
Types = Types(1:kk(1) - 1, :);   % # Remove empty output cells
```

Comment: actually I know that pre allocating is a big issue, but actually I tried to make an intial predicted values for all variables , but some gives errors.. becuase Iam dealing with cells array. for example: I have this code which couldn't give b intial value :         b={};
    for i=1:length(map)
       
        b=[b,map{i,1}];
    end

Comment: @Gloria actually you can predict it. You can count the relevant number of elements in each cell of `map`, and the total sum would be the necessary size of `b`. I'll post an optimized version of your code, and hopefully you'll find its execution time sufficiently fast.

Comment: I tried b=zeros(length(map)) it doesn't work (gives error msg) although the length of map is 13 and b is 13 too!!  thnak you for your support :))

Comment: @Gloria Isn't `b` supposed to be a single row/column array, while `map` is 2-D? Instead, you should be writing `zeros(length(map), 1)`. Also, don't use `length` as it returns the largest dimensions. I believe you want `size(map, 1)`.

Comment: @Gloria I've included an optimized version, try it.

Comment: Thank you for the code.. i just tried it and gave me this error msg :  ??? Error using ==> vertcat
CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.

Error in ==> RKC_FOR_2_INPUTS at 240
    type1 = vertcat(type_fc{:});

Comment: That probably means that you're using row vectors instead of columns. Try replacing `vertcat` with `horzcat`.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm reading it correctly then the function is comparing the values in type 1 with the parent genes in p1, where it finds a match it then returns the corresponding child genes from c1. Is this correct?

In which case a vectorized solution is using *strcmp* to get a logical array of the matches between type1(j) and p1.

```
>> strcmp(type1(j),p1)
```

This can then be used for logical addressing on the array c1, effectively it's a truth table for the values from c1 you want to extract. I'm assuming you are handling these as cell arrays in which case I think something like this should work.

```
function type=type_fc(p1,c1,type1)
type={};
for j=1:length(type1)
    type=[type{:} c1(strcmp(type1(j),p1))'];
end
```

Now whether it makes it any quicker I'm not sure, I was hoping you could test it. This is my suggestion for "vectorized" solution.

Comment: I believe your suggestion for `type_fc` returns an entirely different answer than the OP's.

Comment: Actually I think it was pretty damn close, my mistake was that I was overwriting the variable `type` with every loop on `j`. The code has been corrected. If you create p1 and c1 as cell arrays and `type1={'GO:0008150'}` then for the first iteration both functions return `'GO:0016740' 'GO:0006412'` then feed this back into the function and both will return `'GO:0016787' 'GO:0004672' 'GO:0016779' 'GO:0005215'` which are the first 6 values in `Types`

Comment: Exactly. But still the main problem would be the dynamically growing array :-)